# How to pass more then one parameters from Kendo.Grid to a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Currently I'm passing one parameter to a controller:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("EditingCustom_Read", "TicketReportProperty").Data("GetTicketId()"))
```

And in JavaScript:

```
function GetTicketID() {

    return {
        ticketID: $('#TicketID').attr('text'),
    };
}
```

And controller's method accept `int ticketId` as a parameter

Now I have another parameter that I want to pass:

```
function GetReportID() {
    return {
        reportID: $('#ReportID').attr('text'),
    };
}
```

I tried something like that:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("EditingCustom_Read", "TicketReportProperty").Data("GetTicketID()").Data("GetReportID()"))
```

And controller's method accept `int ticketId, int reportId` as parameters.

But that does not work.

For a moment I thought to have a function that returns 2 parameters concatenated with a comma and pass it to the controller in the similar fashion and then split the string by comma.

Something like that:

```
 function GetData() {   
    return {
        data: $('#TicketID').attr('text') + "," + $('#ReportID').attr('text'),
    };
}

.Read(read => read.Action("EditingCustom_Read", "TicketReportProperty").Data("GetData())
```

And controller's method accept `string data` as parameters.

Not sure if it is the best way to do that?

What is the best solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can just group them in your function:

```
function GetTicketReadParms() {

    return {
        ticketID: $('#TicketID').val(),
        reportID: $('#ReportID').val()
    };
}
```

MVC will match them by name for multiple parms, or within a model class it will match properties (handy for large number of parms).